# Error with minted and TeXMaker : You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package

Tags: errors, texmaker, minted, paths, pygments

I discovered `TeX` and `LaTeX` recently, and I started to learn how to make math documents, but I need to write some source codes in `Python3`. So I choose to use the package `minted`, but I got this error:

> !Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use
> this package

and this error:

> ! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
> probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need the
> outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
> or may be using frozencache with a missing file. See the minted
> package documentation for explanation.

I've seen a lot of posts but none works for me (I've tried to copy the `pygmentize` file in `PATH`: `/usr/bin`, but it doesn't seem to be that. I run `PdfLaTeX` with these options:

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I use TeXMaker on MacOS 10.13 and maybe TeXLive (I don't really remember the distribution but I think it's that).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can you get normal help info after running `pygmentize -h` in Terminal.app? Also I don't think you need to copy `pygmentize` to `/usr/bin`, as far as it is installed with `pip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uninstalled `TexLive` and installed an older version of `MacTex` (My OS isn't compatible with the latest version). I reinstalled `TexMaker` (maybe for nothing) and it works now.

I've also changed the command

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

to

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

because my `pdflatex` was in `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`